# Discord.js How to find all the servers a different discord user is in

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, autocode

I want to make a website where people can change what the bot does on their server. I'm currently using Autocode to make it (using discord.js). I also don't know how to link OAouth2 with the code. This is the full code of what I'm at

```js
// Using Node.js 14.x +
// use "lib" package from npm
const lib = require('lib')({
  token: 'token_here'
});
// make API request
let result = await lib.discord.guilds['@0.2.4'].list({
  limit: 100
});
console.log(result[0]);
```

it works but only gets what guilds the bot is in. I tried to link it to the user but I couldn't find out what to put

Comment: You can only get a list of servers that the bot is in, you cannot access every server one user is in without the bot sharing the same server.

Comment: @Tyler2P it's possible to get with oAuth2 right scopes. Go discord developer docs from [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user-guilds)

Comment: @Neenhila I looked into that but could not figure out how to use it